# how to fetch max record when Between condition matches two records in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
with tb as(
select 1 as PPT_FROM,40 PPT_TO from dual
union
select 15 as PPT_FROM,40 PPT_TO from dual)
select * from tb
where 40 between PPT_FROM and PPT_TO;
```

now input is 40 or 15 fits in both the date range so i want to fetch the maximum record i.e 15 PPT_from and 40 PPT_to

[image]

Comment: Please show us expected results.

Comment: Both `FROM` and `TO` are reserved words (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), i.e. these identifiers need to be delimited as `"FROM"` and `"TO"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `order by` and `fetch`:

```
select *
from tb
where 40 between FROM and TO
order by from desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In old versions of Oracle (pre-12), you need a subquery:

```
select tb.*
from (select tb.*
      from tb
      where 40 between FROM and TO
      order by from desc
     ) tb
where rownum = 1;
```

Note that `FROM` and `TO` are very bad names for columns because they are SQL keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The results you are expecting can be achieved using a simple GROUP BY statement

**Query**

```
WITH
    tb
    AS
        (SELECT 1 AS PPT_FROM, 40 PPT_TO FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 15 AS PPT_FROM, 40 PPT_TO FROM DUAL)
  SELECT MAX (ppt_from) AS ppt_from, ppt_to
    FROM tb
   WHERE 40 BETWEEN PPT_FROM AND PPT_TO
GROUP BY ppt_to;
```

**Results**

```
PPT_FROM | PPT_TO
-----------------
15       | 40
```